# Query optimization (from joining two tables)

Tags: mysql, join, union

Alright so I have this query which regularly shows up in mysql slow log:

```
    (
        SELECT  user_visit_logs.date,user_visit_logs.user_id,invalid_hits,
                unique_hits,non_unique_hits,earned,sites_surfed,earnings
            FROM  user_visit_logs
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  surfer_stats
               ON  user_visit_logs.user_id = surfer_stats.user_id
              AND  user_visit_logs.date = surfer_stats.date
            WHERE  user_visit_logs.user_id = '218' 
    )
    UNION  
    (
        SELECT  surfer_stats.date,surfer_stats.user_id,invalid_hits,unique_hits,
                non_unique_hits,earned,sites_surfed,earnings
            FROM  user_visit_logs
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN  surfer_stats
               ON  user_visit_logs.user_id = surfer_stats.user_id
              AND  user_visit_logs.date = surfer_stats.date
            WHERE  surfer_stats.user_id = '218' 
    )
```

Which basically joins daily data from two tables, as follows:

```
+------------+---------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+--------++--------------+----------+
|           DATA FROM TABLE 1                                                  ||    DATA FROM TABLE 2    |
+------------+---------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+--------++--------------+----------+
|    date    | user_id | invalid_hits | unique_hits | non_unique_hits | earned || sites_surfed | earnings |
+------------+---------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+--------++--------------+----------+
```

As you can see, "date & user_id" are the common columns on which both tables are joined.

The data is then used to generate a HTML table through PHP using mysqli_fetch_assoc.

Mysql explain extended output:

```
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+------------+
|    id    | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys    | key     | key_len | ref                                | rows | filtered | Extra
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+------------+
|    1     | PRIMARY     | user_visit_logs | ref  | user_id,LinkDate | user_id | 8       | const                              | 30   | 100.00   | 
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+------------+
|    1     | PRIMARY     | surfer_stats    | ref  | user_id,date     | user_id | 8       | const                              | 6    | 100.00   | USING WHERE
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+------------+
|    2     | UNION       | surfer_stats    | ref  | user_id          | user_id | 8       | const                              | 6    | 100.00   | 
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+------------+
|    2     | UNION       | user_visit_logs | ref  | user_id,LinkDate | LinkDate| 11      | const,rotate_ptp.surfer_stats.date | 1    | 100.00   | 
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+------------+
|    NULL  | UNION RESULT| <union1,2>      | ALL  | NULL             | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                               | NULL | NULL     | 
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+------------+
```

So question is, is there a way to further optimize this query?
Thanks.

Indexes for TABLE 1 (user_visit_logs):

```
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
|    Keyname  | Type  | Unique | Packed | Column        | Cardinality | Collation | Null | 
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
|    PRIMARY  | BTREE | Yes    | No     | id            | 29097       | A         | No   |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
|    user_id  | BTREE | No     | No     | user_id       | 4849        | A         | No   | 
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
|    LinkDate | BTREE | No     | No     | user_id, date | 4849, 29097 | A         | No   | 
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
```

Indexes for TABLE 2 (surfer_stats):

```
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
|    Keyname  | Type  | Unique | Packed | Column        | Cardinality | Collation | Null | 
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
|    PRIMARY  | BTREE | Yes    | No     | id            | 235428      | A         | No   |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
|    user_id  | BTREE | No     | No     | user_id       | 78476       | A         | No   | 
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
|    date     | BTREE | No     | No     | date          | 1183        | A         | No   | 
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+
```

user_visit_logs

```
CREATE TABLE `user_visit_logs` (
 `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `invalid_hits` int(50) NOT NULL,
 `unique_hits` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `non_unique_hits` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `earned` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `LinkDate` (`user_id`,`date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=604253 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

surfer_stats

```
CREATE TABLE `surfer_stats` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `sites_surfed` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `earnings` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=235787 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G` for your two tables.

Comment: It would be very helpful to see what indexes you have on both tables.  Also if there is any chance there there could be legitimate duplicates in either subquery beware that UNION ALL will eliminate those as well as as the duplicates between the sets.  You can modify it to UNION ALL and expand the WHERE statement of the second subquery `WHERE surfer_stats.user_id = '218' and user_visit_logs.user_id is null`

Comment: I've updated the post with the index information. The only duplicates that may show up are in the "date" column (common to both tables), which is the reason I went with UNION instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: I would expect this query to be logged to the slow log if `log_queries_not_using_indexes` is enabled, because of the `UNION [DISTINCT]`.  Is it actually slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the intersection twice, then go through a de-dup process (`UNION DISTINCT`).  Instead, see the code for `FULL OUTER JOIN` in

```
        SELECT  vl.date, vl.user_id, invalid_hits, unique_hits, non_unique_hits,
                earned, sites_surfed, earnings
            FROM  user_visit_logs AS vl
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  surfer_stats AS ss
               ON  vl.user_id = ss.user_id
              AND  vl.date = ss.date
            WHERE  vl.user_id = '218' 
    )
    UNION  ALL   -- avoid dedup pass
    (
        SELECT  ss.date, ss.user_id, invalid_hits, unique_hits, non_unique_hits,
                earned,sites_surfed, earnings
            FROM  user_visit_logs AS vl
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN  surfer_stats AS ss
               ON  vl.user_id = ss.user_id
              AND  vl.date = ss.date
            WHERE  ss.user_id = '218' 
              AND  vl.user_id IS NULL   -- avoid dup
    )
```

Also, have this on *both* tables:

```
INDEX(user_id, date)
```

Note that the `(255)` after `INT` means nothing.  *Any* `INT` is a 4-byte (32-bit)` integer.

`earnings` cannot be bigger than 99.99999999 ?